# Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to know abt the lifecycle of fragement with respect to activity.

Specifically when an fragement navigates to a new activity with

`startActivityForResult()` and the activity sends back the result.

What will happen, whether `onStart()` or `onResume()` will be invoked ?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it should be `onResume()` as fragment is a 'different' kind of activity!